# Im using Perl for the first time

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

Im taking a Bioinformatics class and I keep getting an "Undefined subroutine &main::Print called at ReverseComp.txt line 4." error

```
# ReverseComp.txt => takes DNA sequence from user
# and returns the reverse complement

print ("please input DNA sequence:\n");
$DNA =<STDIN>;

$DNA =~tr/ATGC/TACG/;   # Find complement of DNA sequence

$DNA =~reverse ($DNA);  # Reverse DNA sequence

print ("Reverse complement of sequence is:\n");

print $DNA."\n";
```

This is my code and I have tried a few different things with line 4 but with no results. Any suggestions? (I am writing this from a prompt, everything looks right....)

Comment: This code is perfectly fine. You might just have written `Print` instead of `print`. Perl identifiers and functions are case sensitive. If you're a beginner with perl (also, in general), it's a good idea to prefix your code with `use strict;` and `use warnings;`.

Comment: The message shows an uppercase 'P'. That ust be a lower case char. But the upper cose char is ot shown in your code. So the code you posted should work.

Comment: You may also want to `chomp` what you read from `STDIN`.  That'll remove the newline or carriage return at the end of the string.

Answer (score 7):

I have some notes related to your code:

1. Name your scripts with the `.pl` extension instead of `.txt`. That is the common accepted extension for Perl scripts (and the `.pm` for Perl modules, libraries with reusable code)
2. Always start your scripts with `use strict; use warnings;`. These sentences helps you to avoid common mistakes.
3. Declare your variables before you use it (See the [my function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html))
4. [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) your input from `STDIN` to remove the newline at the end.
5. The call to reverse function is odd. I think that `$DNA =~ reverse ($DNA);` should be `$DNA = reverse ($DNA);`
6. The [reverse function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/reverse.html) is more common used with Perl arrays; with a string you get the reversed version of that string, as I guest you expected.
7. The [print function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) may take a list of parameters, so you can print several things in one sentence
8. You can omit parentheses in many places, e.g. `reverse($a)` is the same as `reverse $a`. Both are valid, but the latter is more suitable to the Perl style of writing code. The [Perl style guide](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html) is a recommended read

Related to your question, I think your script is right, because the print function exists in Perl, and the error you got says about Print (with uppercase, which is important in Perl). You maybe run a different script that you have posted here.

This is your script with the previous considerations applied (`ReverseComp.pl`):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "please input DNA sequence:\n";
chomp( my $DNA = <STDIN> );

$DNA =~ tr/ATGC/TACG/;    # Find complement of DNA sequence
$DNA = reverse $DNA;      # Reverse DNA sequence

print "Reverse complement of sequence is:\n", $DNA, "\n";
```

In any case, welcome to the fantastic Perl world, and be prepared to enjoy your trip.